# Подскажите по регулярке perl

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Собственно мне нужна регулярка perl для работы с ключевыми словами в программе TextPipe. Сразу перейду к примеру, есть такого рода ключевики:

Buy food **for fat elephant**

Buy apples **for skinny elephant**

Buy carrots **for normal elephant**

Нужно в каждой строчке с помощью регулярки выделить от слова "for" до конца строки. Ну а в TextPipe уже удалить или заменить всё это. Чтобы в результате получились строчки типа:

Buy food

Buy apples

Buy carrots

Очень долго читал про perl, перепробовал разные варианты но так не один и не подошёл, пробовал типа for(.*?)$ но он почему то удаляет всё до конца после первого "For".

Нужна помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пробуйте таким способом захват до конца строки сделать -> `for ([^\r\n]*+)`

Comment: Ничего не понял. В начале вы пишите "_выделить от слова "for" до конца строки_". регулярка у вас верная, в $1 захватит все от for до конца строки. далее вы пишите "_почему то удаляет всё до конца после первого for_". Чем отличается ваше первое "до конца", которое вы хотите получить, от того "до конца", которое вам не подходит ?

Comment: В моём случае, когда я использовал for(.*?)$ то регулярка выделяла и удаляла всё после for до конца самой последней строки, а не для каждой. То есть результатом было просто одна строка с "Buy food".


for.+$ помогло спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решить это так:

**Жадный:** (максимально много раз)

1. ~/for.+$/
2. ~/for.*$/

**Ленивый:** (расширяясь по мере необходимости)

1. ~/for.+?$/
2. ~/for.*?$/

Comment: Но в данном случае между ними нет разницы...

Comment: Да, но это так, чтобы было более развернуто, попросили, я написал :)